# How to change the array you're using for each new element created in a list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to generate 3 lists using javascript, and I got these arrays containing all the strings that I'm going to use in the li elements. What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to change which array to be applied to the next li element that spawns (change array after it has looped once, twice etc.). I tried doing it with another array that contains the other arrays but that didn't seem to work.. The idea is that I'm going to spawn 3 lists that represents 3 different packages you can buy, each listing what comes with the package. Here's how it's supposed to be:

PackageSize

Price

Questions

Langs

respTime

followUp

Any help or general pointers to help me solve this issue is appreciated.

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
//Strings that goes into the lists

var questions = ["10 Questions", "20 Questions", "40 Questions"];
var langs = ["HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT", "HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, PHP, Ruby, Python"];
var respTime = ["Reply within 12 Hours", "Reply within 10 Hours", "Reply within 6 Hours"];
var help = "Get help no matter the difficulty";
var followUp = ["1 follow-up question to each question", "2 follow-up questions to each question"];
var packageSize = ["MINI", "MEDIUM", "LARGE"];
var price = ["5.5 Dollars", "8 Dollars", "14 Dollars"];
var arrays = [questions, langs, respTime, help, followUp, packageSize, price];

//The function generating the list(s)

function list(rows) { //rows decides how many <li> elements there's gonna be in the list

var ul = document.createElement('ul');


for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML=packageSize[i];
    //Here I need to set the 2nd span spawned to price[0-2 depending on which ul that is spawned]
    ul.appendChild(span);
}

for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

document.getElementById('img-holder').appendChild(ul); 

}

list(4);
list(5);
list(5);
```

**SOLUTION:**

I decided to change the entire idea of how the script would flow, I added parameters so that it's easy to change the lists if you would want to. And I also just put 3 arrays with the different packages with all the information about them inside to make it real simple.

```
//The different packages

var mini = ["MINI",
        "5.5 Dollars",
        "10 Questions", 
        "HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT", 
        "Reply within 12 Hours", 
        "Get help no matter the difficulty"];

var medium = ["MEDIUM",
          "8 Dollars",
          "20 Questions", 
          "HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, PHP, Ruby, Python", 
          "Reply within 10 Hours",
          "Get help no matter the difficulty",
          "1 follow-up question to each question"];

var large = ["LARGE",
         "14 Dollars",
         "40 Questions", 
         "HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, PHP, Ruby, Python", 
         "Reply within 6 Hours", 
         "Get help no matter the difficulty", 
         "2 follow-up questions to each question"];

//Function generating the list(s)

function list(rows, package) {

//Create an ul
var ul = document.createElement('ul');

//Create the lists
for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML=package[i];
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(ul); 
}

list(6, mini);
list(7, medium);
list(7, large);
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't doing an array of associative arrays such as `[{questions:10, packageSize:"Mini"}, {questions:20, packageSize:"Medium"}, {questions:40, packageSize:"Large"}]` ?

Comment: Didn't know about it, could you post an example of how to use it?

Comment: @Skram I swear the biggest penny just dropped, I know exactly what to do now. Thank you!

Comment: no problem - glad it helped you out